# "at" unix tool throwing error while trying to start a job

Tags: at-command

Hi I am trying to start a job for tommorow at 10.30 am using at utility.
But its throwing error.Can someone help me with right command to do this?

```
at -f myjob.txt -m -v 10:30AM tommorow
syntax error. Last token seen: t
Garbled time
```